# Passing URL parameters to webapp2.RequestHandler in python results in 'None'

Tags: python, webapp2, requesthandler

I have the following web application, which has 1 handler:

```
class GetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, name):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(name)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                    (r'/get(.)*', GetHandler)
], debug=False)
```

I'm running this application in local host port 8080.
And I'm sending this request in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/get?name=Peter
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
None
```

Although I'm passing a parameter. I was expecting the output to be as I passed the parameter.
Am I missing something here? Why my handler doesn't work as expected?